# labelled graph characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Given the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ for a simple connected graph, the characteristic polynomial is defined as:
$$ p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})$$

Now if an edge between vertex $i$ and $j$ is "labelled" with another variable $x$, then we could consider a bivariate polynomial:

$$ f(\lambda,x) = \det(\lambda \mathbf{I} + x (\mathbf{e}_{ij}+\mathbf{e}_{ji}) - \mathbf{A})$$

where $\mathbf{e}_{ij}$ is the matrix with all entries zero except row $i$, column $j$, which is 1.

Or similarly, if the vertex $i$ was labelled with the variable $x$, we could consider the polynomial:

$$ g(\lambda,x) = \det(\lambda \mathbf{I} + x \mathbf{e}_{ii} - \mathbf{A})$$

This of course could be extended to more labels, but I'm mostly interested in graphs with a single label at the moment.

> Have these been studied before, and is there a name for these kinds of polynomials?

I'm particularly interested in learning about simple connected graphs which are non-isomorphic, and have the same "labelled characteristic polynomial", but differ only by a single labelled edge like 
$$\det(\lambda \mathbf{I} + x(\mathbf{e}_{ij}+\mathbf{e}_{ji}) - A) = \det(\lambda \mathbf{I} + x(\mathbf{e}_{mn}+\mathbf{e}_{nm}) - A)$$
where $mn$ and $ij$ are distinct edges. I'm assuming that is possible given the difficulty of graph isomorphism, but I'm not sure how to go about constructing such graphs.

Comment: I recommend you to ask this question at MathOverflow (MO), because it seems too specific for MSE and also chances to obtain a qualified answer look better at MO.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I don't really understand the relation between the two sites.  I kind of got the impression that MO was for serious researchers. I dont even have a math degree. I'm just curious about math.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but your question is specific. For instance, I have a math degree and wrote some papers in graph theory, but I don't know an answer to your question.

Comment: Did you ask this on MO then? I'm interested too! Also, I haven't had time to properly look at it, but a lot on graph labelling in here (and a tremendous compilation of references): http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/DS6/pdf

Comment: @kbau I finally asked on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247416/labelled-graph-characteristic-polynomial I'm still digesting the references Alex gave, but based on his answer I think I should have said "color" instead of "label" a vertex/edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you wish to obtain an answer here then I confirm my above comments that your should talk with a specialist. My google search extended my knowledge of an answer not far from zero.

I didn’t find exactly the same generalization of a characteristic polynomial of a graph as you proposed but I guess there should be some of them. See, for instance a paper “[A Generalization of the Characteristic Polynomial of a Graph](http://theory.epfl.ch/vishnoi/Publications_files/LVgraphpoly.pdf)” by Richard J. Lipton and Nisheeth K. Vishnoi.

Personally I see two natural directions in which a further generalization may be useful. The first is a problem of an isomorphism of vertex or edge colored graphs. The second is a problem of a simultaneous isomorphism of two graphs with common vertex set (If I remember it right, a corresponding problem for the similarity of pairs of matrices is so called “wild problem” and when specialists in matrices encounter an equivalent problem they said with respect: “O-o, so it is the wild problem” and stop. [Here](http://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/f10/algebra1-lect8new.pdf) is even written (in Russian) that it is not expected to obtain a reasonable answer to such a problem).

> how to go about constructing non-isomorphic graphs with matching characteristic polynomial with a single "edge label".

I suggest such graphs exist, because the quest to find two non-isomorphic graphs with matching characteristic polynomials (so called *cospectral graphs*) and even more additional restrictions, looks elaborated. See, for instance, the following papers:

- Anthony DiGenio “[A Construction of Cospectral Graphs](https://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-042811-121510/unrestricted/DiGenio_-_A_Construction_of_Cospectral_Graphs.pdf)”.
- Haruo Hosoya, Kyoko Ohta, Masaki Satomi “[Topological twin graphs II. Isospectral polyhedral graphs with nine and ten vertices](http://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match44/match44_183-200.pdf)”.
- M. Randić , W. R. Müller , J. V. Knop , and N. Trinajstić  “[The Characteristic Polynomial as a Structure Discriminator](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci970242r?journalCode=jcics1)”.