# Examples of cospectral and non-isomorphic trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I found this paper about "Almost all trees are cospectral" as the number of nodes go asymptotically large.

But it is pretty hard to do experiments to find cospectral but non-isomorphic trees for small number of nodes. Are there simple examples with very few nodes?

Answer (score 2):

One of small examples is on Fig. 2 of the paper “[Topological twin graphs II. Isospectral polyhedral graphs with nine and ten vertices](http://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match44/match44_183-200.pdf)” by Haruo Hosoya, Kyoko Ohta, and Masaki Satomi.

PS. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871174/labelled-graph-characteristic-polynomial/1888738#1888738) my answer contains few references about cospectral graphs.